# For loop for table data

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, html-table

I need data in a table to be filled by javascript loops. The first table data should just be numbers 1-24. This is where I used a for loop.

```
for(int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {

}
```

The second set of table data should be sum of $150 + $299 (value) incremented through a for loop 12 times. The first number should be $449, second number should be $449 + $299, etc.,

I would like a loop that is something like

```
for (int j = 1; j < 13; j += 299);
    value += j;
      j++; ( I don't know if this is correct)
```

Here is my code in DevExpress:

```
 @for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
 {
    <tr class="bundleRow">
       <td class="numbers">@i</td>
       <td class="totals"></td>
       <td class="numbers">@(i + 12)</td>
       <td class="totals"></td>
     </tr>
  }
```

Here is the complete code:

```
<div class="myleads-modals">

<!--Info Modal-->
                    <div class="col col-xs-7 col-xs-5 no-gutters border-left contentbox">
                        <div class="radio-stations">
                            <div class="customModalBtnContainer">
                                <button id="modalTrigger">Media Bundle</button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="customModalContainer" class="customModal">

                                <!-- Modal content -->
                                <div id="customModalContent">
                                    <span class="closeCustomModal">&times;</span>
                                    <div class="mediaBundleTitle">MEDIA TITLE</div>
                                 <table class="mediaBundle">
                                     <tr class-="bundleRow">
                                         <th class="numofSpotsTitle"># of Spots</th>
                                         <th class="raiTotalsTitle">RAI Total</th>
                                         <th class="numofSpotsTitle"># of Spots</th>
                                         <th class="raiTotalsTitle">RAI Total</th>
                                     </tr>
                                     @for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
                                     {
                                        <tr class="bundleRow">
                                            <td class="numbers">@i</td>
                                            <td class="totals"><span>$</span></td>
                                            <td class="numbers">@(i + 12)</td>
                                            <td class="totals"><span>$</span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                         }
                                 </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <script>
                                $(document).ready(function () {
                                    $("#modalTrigger").click(function () {
                                        $(".customModal").show();
                                    });
                                    $(".closeCustomModal").click(function () {
                                        $(".customModal").hide();
                                    });
                                });
                            </script>
```

Comment: can you provide the complete code of your problem i mean html and input data ?

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan I uploaded the complete code.

Comment: not like that just the inputs you want to display and part of html where you want to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use formula (150 + i * 299)

```
@for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++){
     <tr class="bundleRow">
       <td class="numbers">@i</td>
       <td class="totals"><span>$</span></td>
       <td class="numbers">@(150+i*299)</td>
       <td class="totals"><span>$</span></td>
     </tr> }
```